# Processing an uploaded Zip File in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure function that gets triggered when a blob gets uploaded to a certain directory.  It processes a zip file.  When I upload the file to the container with the Azure storage explorer, it works perfectly.  When I upload it through web API, it blows up.  If I down load that file it seems to be corrupt, however, it is the same size as the source, and when I do a beyond compare between the 2, then seem, identical (and beyond compare seems to see the contents of the zip file).

Here is the upload code:

```
public async Task<UploadedFileDescription> StoreCatalog(HttpRequestMessage Request)
{
    UploadedFileDescription upload = new UploadedFileDescription();  // my return description
    var guidString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string fileName = guidString + ".zip";  //add the .zip extenstion
    upload.fileName = fileName;
    string storageConnection = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString");
    CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnection);
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("uploadedzips");
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
    var stream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
    return upload;
}
```

The file gets into blob storage fine.

Then the triggered Azure function fires and blows up on this line:

```
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(myBlob);
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destinationStorage);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(destinationContainer);

var catalogService = Helpers.container.Resolve<ICatalogService>();
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)    <------blows up here with the msg
```

```
System.IO.InvalidDataException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.
  Source=System.IO.Compression
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadCentralDirectory()
   at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.get_Entries()
   at DentaCAD.AzureFunctions.ProcessUploadedZip.Run(Stream myBlob, String name, TraceWriter log) in C:\repo\ProcessUploadedZip.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync(TReflected instance, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.<InvokeAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
```

When that line gets hit when uploading the file manually, there are 163 entries in the archive (all small `jpg` files)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

it could be a matter of the wrong MIME type.
try changing the content type to `"application/zip"` instead of `"application/x-zip-compressed"`

Comment: That is how I had it originally.  When I upload the same zip file with Azure Storage Explorer(which works fine), it was setting it to "application/x-zip-compressed" which is why i switched.  When I download the 'corrupted' zip its the same size as the original one that was uploaded (and is valid), so I am totally at a loss.

Comment: could you try separating the issue? instead of starting from iterating over the ```Entries``` property, are you able to access the ```archive``` variable at all? also try wrapping the code in try/catch block and debug it line by line - when the exception is caught, have a look at the ```InnerException``` property of the exception, anything there?